# Why cant I write/read from my Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working app which is connected to my Firebase Project.
I implemented a working Login on my App, which works just perfectly and
synchronyzes correctly with Firebase Authentication.
What I want to do now (after you logged in correctly), is to show you
data from a realtime database, but for some reason, i can neither write
parameters trough a button click on my database, nor can I read from it...
I followed tutorials 1:1, but as soon as they click on a button and suddendly
write on their database, it doesn't work for me no matter what i try..
Maybe you guys could help me? :-(

Note: My Firebase Project is correctly connected to my flutter project, all packages are included.

```
class _DataAdminState extends State<DataAdmin> {
  final dref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
  setData() {
    dref.child("Info").set({
      'id': '01',
      'name': 'Tom',
      'contact': '0xxxxxxx',
      'country': 'USA',
    });
  }...
```

```
TextButton(onPressed: setData, child: Text('Store data')),
```

Comment: For future questions about the Firebase Realtime Database, please tag with `firebase-realtime-database` and not with `google-cloud-firestore`.

Comment: Do you see any errors? Did you check the read-write permissions in firebase?

Comment: No errors, read and write is set true: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}